# Is there a driver for the Kensington VeriMark USB fingerprint key?

Tags: drivers, usb, fingerprint-reader

I'd like to protect my laptop but find a secure password too tedious. The Kensington VeriMark (https://www.kensington.com/us/us/7772/k67977ww/verimark-fingerprint-key) looks like a great solution, but their website only mentions Windows support. I take it that the `fingerprint-gui` package helps with built-in fingerprint scanners, but I've not received feedback on feasibility from the forum. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Did you figure any option with "small" (dongle size) sensor?

Comment: OP please tell us if you found anything

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found a fix yet - please upvote the question to raise awareness of the issue!

Answer (score 3):

So the production you looking at doesn't appear to be out of the box, I own two of these. I have Ubuntu 17.10 running on my laptop. Problem seems to be that the device isn't properly recognized so it's not found by FringerPrint GUI. I think it may be just the process of finding the correct driver but I haven't had any luck as of yet. I do know that the device seems to be using a Synaptics Inc. driver. For other solutions there is a pretty decent list here [devices](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint/Supported_devices/) and here [devices](http://www.neurotechnology.com/cgi-bin/fingerprint-scanners.cgi?group=platforms_linux_mac)